# In Jenkins, How can I pass Job parameter values to a shell script which runs inside 'Check job prerequisites' section?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins, How can I pass Job parameter values to a shell script which runs inside 'Check job prerequisites' section?[image]

In the attached image, as you can see I am executing a shell script in the jenkins job's prerequisites part but want to pass a few job parameters to the shell script. But not able to do so, since jenkins doesn't recognize these parameters in prerequisites section.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try removing sh from the command.
2. Verify if the relative path provided is correct. Click on "?" to see how this option really works.
3. The variables you are passing, are these environment variables? Check if Jenkins recognizes these variables.